# NI-USB Daqmx applying low pass filter with defined cut off frequency by python

Tags: python, lowpass-filter, nidaqmx, bandpass-filter

I am trying to acquire voltage and temperature data with NI-USB 6341. The data is noisy and requires a filter, in my cases a low pass filter and a bandpass filter, separately. I do prefer to do it by python functions, based on the NI-DAQmx Python Documentation, the **nidaqmx.constants** of **FilterType** should be imported, but where **FilterType** should be used and how I can define the cut off frequencies for low pass and bandpass filters?